# Why does action bar back button goes back to the top of the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview

How can I change my action bar back button code for it not to go to the top of the recyclerview when someone clicks on it, I want it to be exactly like the back button on my device where when you click it; it goes back to the position you left your recyclerview, thanks!

Comment: We need code or a snippet and it would be nice to see a photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same problem.

My situation:
I have recyclerView and when I click one of the items then it go to  the new detailActivity, when returning from it with phone back button then the recyclerView is on the same position but when using actionBar back then it jumps on top of the recyclerView.

Goal:
That the actionBar back button should work like phone back button

My solution:
 I deleted these lines in the manifest file. This is the part of DetailActivity

```
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.app.MainActivity" />
```

In the DetailActivity I added this line to onCreate

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and in onOptionsItemSelected() method I added these lines

```
 if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
```

Works for me